# Directional derivative understanding

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

[Beginning multivariable question.] I have just been introduced to a theorem that says $$D_uf(x)=\nabla f(x)\cdot u.$$ So in the two-dimensional case, $$\nabla f(x,y)= \langle f_x(x,y),f_y(x,y)\rangle \cdot \langle a,b\rangle$$

I don't really understand this. It seems to me that $f_x$ could be 0 and $f_y$ could be 0, there could still be a nonzero derivative in the direction halfway between the $x$ and $y$ axes.

My intuition is that such a situation would violate the theorem -- so I must be misunderstanding something. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are correct that the derivative could be zero in the directions of both axes, but not in some diagonal direction. However, that can never happen if the function is *differentiable* at the relevant point. Being differentiable is a stronger condition than the existence of both partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

First, in cartesian coordinates we have a quantity known as gradient defined the following way:

$$ \nabla F = < \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}>$$

Now, it may be noted that:

$$ F(x+ \Delta x, y+ \Delta y) = F(x, y + \Delta y) +  \Delta x \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y+\Delta y)+\text{higher order terms in x } \tag{1}$$

And, further we can write:

$$ F(x,y + \Delta y) = F(x,y) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y)\Delta y + +\text{higher order terms in y}  \tag{2}$$

This leads to:

$$ F(x+ \Delta x, y+ \Delta y) = F(x,y) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y)\Delta y + +\text{higher order terms in y} +  \Delta x \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y+\Delta y)+\text{higher order terms} \tag{1}$$

Or,
$$ F(x+ \Delta x, y+ \Delta y) \approx F(x,y) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y)\Delta y +\Delta x \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y+\Delta y)\tag{3}$$

It may be noted that for small enough $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ we can write: $$ \Delta x \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} (x,y+\Delta y) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y) \Delta y $$

This leads to:
$$ F(x+ \Delta x, y+ \Delta y) \approx F(x,y) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x,y)\Delta y +\Delta x \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y)\tag{4}$$

Or,

$$ F(x+ \Delta x, y+ \Delta y) \approx F(x,y) + \nabla F \cdot <\Delta x, \Delta y>\tag{4}$$

(1) and (2) were based on Taylor series/ linear approximation to F. I have written about it [here](https://buraian.medium.com/a-brief-introduction-to-taylor-series-47416e7b9123)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the statement $\nabla f(x,y)=(f_x(x,y),f_y(x,y))\cdot(a,b)$ is incorrect. $\nabla f(x,y)$ is called the *gradient* of $f$. It exists whenever $f$ is a function $\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$ and all of $f$'s partial derivatives exist. For multivariate functions it is always a vector, for single variate functions it reduces to $f'$. For $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ it is defined $\nabla f(x,y)=(f_x(x,y),f_y(x,y))$. If you evaluate $\nabla f$ at a point $(x,y)$ you will either get a non-zero vector pointing in the direction of maximum increase of $f$ at $(x,y)$, or a *stationary point* where $\nabla f=\mathbf{0}$ (if you haven't already you will learn how the concept of a stationary point generalises to the multivariable case.).

As an example, consider $f(x,y)=x^2y^2$ (plot it in WolframAlpha.) The gradient of $f(x,y)=x^2y^2$ is $\nabla f(x,y)=(2xy^2,2x^2y)$. Stationary points exist whenever $x$ or $y$ are zero. We have $\nabla f(1,1) = (2,2)$, which points in the direction of maximum increase of $f$ at $(1,1)$, or up the "steepest slope" of $f$ at $(1,1)$.

The *directional derivative* of a function $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$ in the direction $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ at the point $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as 
$$D_\mathbf{a} f(\mathbf{x}) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(\mathbf{x}+h\mathbf{a})-f(\mathbf{x})}{h}.$$
It is clearly a different object to the gradient.

As an example, consider the same function $f$ from before. The directional derivative is,
\begin{align}
D_{(a,b)} f(x,y)&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ (x+ha)^2(y+hb)^2-x^2y^2}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\, (ay + bx + abh)(2xy + ahy + bhx + abh^2) \\
&= 2xy(ay +bx)
\end{align}
Evaluating at $(1,1)$ in the direction $(-1,-1)$ gives $-4$.

The theorem you referred to in your question requires that $f$ be *differentiable*. The terminology is confusing because this has a technical meaning you will learn later. For now, just remember that the theorem only applies if all of $f$'s partial derivatives exist and are *continuous*. If this is the case, then the theorem applies. Thus it is impossible to find a function with *continuous* partial derivatives equal to zero along each axis at a given point, but with a non zero directional derivative in some other direction at that point.

With our example function $f$, we had $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2xy^2$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2x^2y$, both of which are continuous. We had $\nabla f(1,1)= (2,2)$ and $\nabla f(1,1)\cdot (-1,-1)=-4$ which was $D_{(-1,-1)} f(1,1)$ from before!

Comment: Regarding the definition of directional derivative, I am a bit confused about the length of the direction vector $\vec{v}=(a,b)$. From your description, it seems that $\vec v$ needs not to be a unit vector, so the consequence is that $D_{\lambda\vec v} f=\lambda D_{\vec v}f$, which is strange to me (i.e., both vectors point to the same direction but have different directional derivatives). I guess I must missed something here.

Comment: @bruin See the [directional derivatives Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#Using_only_direction_of_vector) for a discussion of this point. You can certainly restrict the definition to just unit vectors, but the theorem also works in general. In some contexts you might not have a definition of distance and hence not be able to define unit vectors at all, but the theorem will still work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I looked into the wikipedia page, which contains related discussion. Later I came across L.H. Loomis's "Advanced Calculus", he noted in page 147 that *Strictly speaking, we are misusing the word "direction", because different vectors can have the same direction.* Then I am a kind of relieved :)

Comment: Why did you drop the letter 'a' in your name? :p @bruin